# Can I open a file manager as root without using terminal in xubuntu

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, xfce

I am trying to launch file manager as root in the panel I get a error when I put `sudo` in front of the command `exo-open --launch FileManager` it returns a error.  However, if I put the same command in a XFCE terminal (not the emulator) I launch file manager as root and it works. I am very confused

Comment: You really should always post the error message into the question for us to be able to help

Comment: Why not make a launcher (.desktop file) running gks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Please note that it can be very dangerous to run your file manager as a root user.***

You can use `gksu` for launching GUI applications as root.

Install `gksu` from a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

After it is installed, you can now launch it without a terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing in:

```
gksu thunar
```

Thunar is the default file manager in Xubuntu.

---

**NOTE:** `gksu` is no longer available for Ubuntu 18.04.  However, `pkexec` is installed by default in 18.04.

You can also use `pkexec` as well to launch.  Same as above and change `gksu` to `pkexec`.

```
pkexec thunar
```

If you don't want to open a terminal window, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up a run window and you can type in that command that way you are not leaving any terminal windows open:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hard-to-use security won't be used.  I hope the following answer convincingly demonstrates the imprudence of Debian's failure to replace gksu with a work-alike facility based on PolicyKit.

The following two easy steps will provide  with one-click access to thunar (or any other app) with root privileges:

Create an app launcher in which the command line is:

```
sudo thunar
```

As root, edit /etc/sudoers.d/ so that it contains:

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Afterwards, **whoever uses username's X-window session will have root privileges**.  Since the loss of gksu, however, it's an easy way to have one-click access to a root-privileges app from a non-root GUI.